# Onsen UI Infinite List, setting the modifier as 'longdivider does not work

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am using an infinite list in my web app. Here is my angular code for creating the list:

```
unverifiedPicturesInfiniteList.delegate = {
  createItemContent: function(i) {

    var pictureObject = $scope.unverifiedPictures[i];
    var currentPictureID = $scope.unverifiedPictures[i]._id + 'VERIFYBUTTON';

    var profilePictureSource = '/getProfilePic/' + pictureObject.profilePicture.fileName;

    return  ons._util.createElement(
      "<ons-list-item modifier='longdivider' style='background-color: #C4C4C4;'>" + 
      "<div>" +
        "<img src=" + profilePictureSource + "></img>" + 
        "<br/><button id=" + currentPictureID + " class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Verify Picture</button>" +
      "</div>" + 
      "</ons-list-item>"
    );
  },
  countItems: function() {
    return $scope.unverifiedPictures.length;
  },
  calculateItemHeight: function() {
    return 275;
  }
};
```

If you look in the 'ons-list-item' tag, you will see where I'm setting the modifier and changing the background color for the list element.

The color appears correctly as I defined it, but the longdivider does not.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in OnsenUI?

**UPDATE**
I think it is a bug because the 'chevron' modifier appears correctly. I will link to this on the Onsen UI Forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually both modifiers are implemented in different ways, so I don't think that's the issue.

It may just be a browser/zooming issue. Make sure you're not viewing the page zoomed out. The borders are supposed to be only "half a pixel", so maybe your browser just doesn't show them properly. They should be visible on actual devices.

Another option would be if your items are say `276` px instead of `275` - maybe you're just hiding the border.

**Update** - I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/QEkzdq?editors=0010) with code similar to yours and noticed - you are setting the background to `#c4c4c4`, and the border is supposed to be `#ccc`, so it's just that you don't see it because the whole item basically has the same color. Check out the codepen where I changed the color to `#eee` and you will see the border there (probably). If not - then it's a browser issue.

Sidenote: since you're using angular you may be interested in setting `configureItemScope` rather than `createItemContent`

Comment: Thanks for the help again Ilia.